# Non-face "deepfakes" in videos

Tags: computer-vision, algorithm-request, model-request, deepfakes

Instead of changing faces (like [James Bond to Putin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWnTs2MMYs0)) what if, given sufficient training data, I wanted to:

- Remove or add some windows from a brick house?
- Convert a glass of red wine to a glass of white wine?
- Remove the infamous [the Starbucks cup](https://www.usmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Game-of-Thrones-Starbucks-Cup-On-Camera-Season-8-Episode-4.jpg) from Game of Thrones?

Although deepfakes are notoriously hungry to train, the pre-trained weights are [plug-and-play](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab).

Does there exist any equivalent for non-face objects?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Artificial Intelligence SE. If you're looking for a **pre-trained** model, your question is off-topic here. If you're looking for the name of a model (pre-trained or not) that you could use to solve this task, then your question becomes on-topic. Please, take the time to read our [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So, please, edit your post to clarify what you mean by "plug-and-play".

Comment: Hi @nbro. I am not looking for a pre-trained. I am looking for the name of this model, the family of this model, maybe a few paper outlining this model. I have my own training and testing data on tap. Sorry if that was unclear. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Can you please include this info in your post directly (so that I can delete these comments to avoid clutter)? Thank you.